# How can i trigger a onFailure event for g:formRemote?

Tags: grails, groovy, response, grails-controller

I am using grails and i have a basic form remote

```
<g:formRemote name="add" onSuccess="close();" onFailure="dispayErrors();\"
                  url="[controller: ctx, action: 'insert']" method="POST" class="add">
 //Some inputs + submit button
</g:formRemote>
```

My question is what shoud the insert method return for so that onFailure is triggered?
Thanx

Comment: there's no need to add a semicolon at the end of each `onXXX` attribute value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the controller action (temporarily I presume) to

```
def insert = {
    render status: HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

    // This also works
    //response.sendError HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
}
```

If you're using Grails 2.0 it is recommended to define your action as a method rather than a closure:

```
def insert() {
    render status: HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
}
```

Comment: I didn't know methods were the preferred way of implementing actions in 2.0.  For further reading: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#understandingControllersAndActions